# Does PHP have an input field

Tags: php, html, ussd

I am developing a php code designed for a USSD platform. For those of you who dont know what it means its a text based application that works on both high and low -end phones ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data ). 
The application involves displaying a short menu, and a (form) input field to enter a reply.

The issue is that USSD dislikes HTML code. Any HTML code displays as HTML code which is undesirable, thus the section in my applications is suppose to display a form input field shows as html code rather than a rendered form input field. 
Is there any other way to display form input fields in PHP rather than including html code?

```
 <?php

echo "Options \n
1. Come home
2. Go to Spena 
4. Go to Mungono";

echo "
<form>
<input type='text' id='opt' value='Response: '  onchange='opt()' />
</form> ";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. Plain PHP does not come with helpers like ASP or ColdFusion does. So you have to echo your html code by hand.

However you can try using a form builder class like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/).

Answer (score 1):

PHP generates html or text output that can be used any way you like, so the question is what your clients are able to read/process.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, my clients are able html code on their phones, which isnt desirable. I need a method to make it possible for their phones to render form input fields as form input fields and not html code.

Comment: Different technologies have different means of displaying and handling forms, if you are rendering html the only way is using html input fields. You could integrate your php app with a native phone app (e.g. for iPhone you could build an iOS app that works with a php backend, and the form would be built and handled using objective-c and the cocoa touch APIs.) So it depend on what kind of phones your clients have exactly. iOS? Android? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) but that won't do you much good, since your problem is not what is supported by PHP but what is supported by USSD … except that as far as I can tell (from reading the [Wikipedia page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data), USSD is just the transport protocol.

There will be another protocol (possibly WAP) which is used for the data you pass to the phone, and you need to present your request for input in a format that is compatible with whatever it supports there.

PHP is a programming language. It can output whatever you like. You need to find out what you need to output to the phone.

Comment: I need to output to the phone a form input field in a format that isnt in HTML? is this possible?

Comment: @SirBT — As I said, you can output whatever you like. If the format you are using supports a form input field then you can output one in that format. You need to determine what format it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked PHP commandline [I/O streams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)?
I am not sure about working with USSD.